# Open/Free Books on Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, book-recommendation

I'm looking for *open* books on abstract algebra, other than [Judson's AATA](https://abstract.ups.edu). I want one with a good number of exercises (and solutions, preferably), this one covers the rest. Does anyone know of one?

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1174572/open-publicly-available-textbooks-worth-their-salt) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808279/open-source-abstract-algebra-textbooks) are similar questions. The first one has many answers and the second is markedly different, but answers specific to abstract algebra, with brief descriptions of each book (too much to expect in the [first](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1174572/open-publicly-available-textbooks-worth-their-salt)) might help someone someday.

Comment: I believe Serg Lang has his available for free.

Comment: Some free math resources are available [here](https://github.com/rossant/awesome-math#algebra)

Comment: @anonymous: Lang's Algebra is available on line, but I think it is a pirate copy.

Comment: The AMS has a site for open math notes: https://www.ams.org/open-math-notes . [Here are the search results for 'abstract algebra'](https://www.ams.org/open-math-notes/omn-advanced-search?submitAction=quickSearch).

Comment: It's not a book, but Paul Garrett's algebra notes are among the finest I've read: https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~garrett/m/algebra/

(Personally, I find them preferable to many books on algebra too!)

Answer (score 1):

This builds on [Viktor Vaughn](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/22912/viktor-vaughn)'s comment:
Margaret Morrow's [notes](http://jiblm.org/downloads/dlitem.php?id=87&category=jiblmjournal) (PDF, 130 KB and free) in the Journal of Inquiry Based Learning introduce group theory with a sequence of directed questions. Rings and Fields are not covered.

I think this would be a great introduction, but it might help to skim through each section from another text after going through it in the notes, for a cheesy coverage of the motivation and intuition.
These don't have solutions or 'hard' questions, but the solutions can be found in any standard text.

I suggest going through examples of groups after the first section - it will help later.

Answer (score 0):

I have read and really enjoyed John Fraleigh's book "A First Course In Abstract Algebra". It was very reader friendly and helped me understand deeply a lot of the fundamental concepts of abstract algebra. You can find it for free here: [A first course in abstract algebra](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxkaWRhc2Jsb2d8Z3g6N2U2ZjI2MDc4YzdiNmU3)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it, but I'm looking for books that are legitimately available. Want to incentivise such authors. (Maybe stackexchange should have a separate tag for open content)